# Power opamp 'floating' output

Tags: power, operational-amplifier, ac, signal, load

So I had to design an amplifier with a 'floating' output. (I don't know if floating is the right word, it's the direct translation from dutch.)

See the picture below ( I drew it whilst sitting in the train so it doesn't look very nice)
[image]

I don't know the theory behind this but I suspect that one of the signals works as sort of a reference signal for the other one. So the electric potential alternates over the load.

Can somebody verify/clarify this for me?

Thank you,
Matthijs

Comment: The diagram is unreadable.

Comment: I added a clearer picture. Don't worry about the text, it's more of less the same as in the post.

Comment: If you open the picture in a new tab you can zoom, it's high resolution.

Comment: It may be called a bridge-tied load here. Could you check and see if that fits?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge-tied_load

Comment: It is a bridge tied load indeed, it is also a bridged amplifier. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridged_and_paralleled_amplifiers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a H bridge amplifier: -

[image]

The top output has a voltage that is \$V_{IN}\cdot (1 + \frac{R_1}{R_2})\$ and the bottom output is the inverse of this. Clearly I'm talking about AC voltages because the input amplifier removes DC/low frequencies.

Comment: I get it now I think. I was confused by someone who told me the signal would cancel out each other, which is simply wrong. If Vin=1V and (1+R2/R1)=1, the upper output clamp would be 1V and the lower output clamp would be -1V. So the current would flow from upper to lower clamp. Alternating Vin would alternate the current flow between the output clamps.